# "error: function definition is not allowed here" w/ curly brackets in C?

Tags: c, function, debugging

hello i'm trying to create an online form of one of those little paper fortune tellers. this is the WIP code and I've mostly debugged it but I keep getting these two errors

```
fortune.c:58:3: error: function definition is not allowed here
fortune.c:79:4: error: function definition is not allowed here
```

ive looked up the question a lot and it keeps telling me that you have to define your functions outside of main because they're global or whatever but i already invoked them outside of the main function and before it begins, with the first couple lines. i've also tried just putting the whole code towards the top but it looks ugly to me like that and it causes like 20 bugs. i was just relieved to get all the errors down to single digits lol.
so here's the code any help would be appreciated. this is my first time coding. *brick'd*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  

void fortune1(void);
void fortune2(void);

int main (void)
{
    
int fort; 
int tune;
    
// get color
char color; // []?
printf("Color?\n");
scanf("%s", &color);
int count;
count = strlen(&color);  
{
if(count % 2 == 0) 
    int num1; 
    printf("Number?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
        if(num1 % 2 == 0)
        {
            fortune1(); 
        }
        else
        {
            fortune2();
        }
}
{   
    int num2; // []?
    printf("Number?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num2); 
        if(num2 % 2 == 0)
        {
            fortune1();
        }
        else
        {
            fortune2();
        }
}
}


// fortune1 function
void fortune1(void)
  {                   
        do
        {
            int fort;
            printf("Fortune?\n");
            scanf("%d", &fort);
        } while (fort < 5 || fort > 0); //must be in range 1-4
            if(fort = 1);
                printf("fortune1");
            if(fort = 2);
                printf("fortune2");
             if(fort = 3);
                printf("fortune3");
            if(fort = 4);
                printf("fortune4");
    }

    
// fortune2 function

void fortune2(void)
   {                
        do
        {
            int tune;
            printf("Fortune?\n");
            scanf("%d", &tune);
         } while (tune < 9 || tune > 4)
            if(tune = 5);
                printf("fortune5");
            if(tune = 6);
                printf("fortune6");
            if(tune = 7);
                printf("fortune7");
            if(tune = 8);
                printf("fortune8");
    }
}

'''
```

Comment: Fix your indentation and the problem will become apparent.

Comment: There are multiple systemic problems here.  It seems you need to brush up on the syntax of `if` and block scope.  Almost every one of your if-statements is incorrect.  You also have a missing semi-colon on one of your do-while loops.  One broken if-statement will hide a required variable definition (for `num1`).  You have variable scope errors in the "fortune" functions.  If you are getting multiple errors, look at the _first_ error and fix that.  Sometimes one error can cause other misleading errors.

Comment: Not relevant to your main problem, but `if (tune = 5)` and the like will not do what you intended for it to do. The comparison operator in C is `==`. Enable your compiler's warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  

void fortune1(void);
void fortune2(void);

int main (void)
{

    int fort; 
    int tune;

    // get color
    char color[10]; // []? if you're using string, then use array
    printf("Color?\n");
    scanf("%s", &color);
    int count;
    count = strlen(color);  //if u use &, you'll count the variable address
    
    if(count % 2 == 0) 
    {
        int num1; 
        printf("Number1?\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
            if(num1 % 2 == 0)
            {
                 fortune1(); 
            }
            else
            {
                 fortune2();
            }
    }
    else
    {
        //i dunno if this part is inside if or else 
    int num2; // []?
    printf("Number2?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num2); 
        if(num2 % 2 == 0)
        {
            fortune1();
        }
        else
        {
            fortune2();
        }
    }
}


// fortune1 function
void fortune1(void)
  {         
        int fort;          
        do
        {
            printf("Fortune1?\n");
            scanf("%d", &fort);
        } while (fort >= 5 || fort <= 0); //must be in range 1-4
        // i change the condition iniside while, because if not, the code will always looping
        if(fort == 1) // == not =
            printf("fortune1");
        if(fort == 2)
            printf("fortune2");
        if(fort == 3)
            printf("fortune3");
        if(fort == 4)
           printf("fortune4");
        //don't use ; after if
    }


// fortune2 function

void fortune2(void)
   {     
        int tune;           
        do
        {
            printf("Fortune2?\n");
            scanf("%d", &tune);
         } while (tune >= 9 || tune <= 4); //; after while in do while
         if(tune == 5)
            printf("fortune5");
         if(tune == 6)
            printf("fortune6");
         if(tune == 7)
            printf("fortune7");
         if(tune == 8)
            printf("fortune8");
    }
```

please tell me if i'm wrong